# Uploading images from react-native to laravel REST API

Tags: ajax, reactjs, laravel, react-native, expo

I'm using EXPO-CLI's image picker for uploading images and got them to render client sided but now trying to send them to my Laravel REST API and move them to a folder. The problem is, laravel isn't recognizing my formdata image via react-native as a file.

React Native Code:

```
const [image, setImage] = useState('');
const [data, setData] = useState('');

  pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1]
    });
    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
      setData(result)
    }
  };

 const addNew = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", name);
    formData.append("description", description);
    formData.append("file", {type: 'image/jpg', uri:image, name:'uploaded.jpg'});
    formData.append("price", price);
    formData.append("category", categoryID);
    const heads = 
    {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  }
    axios
      .post(
        "http://mydomain/products/store",
        formData,
        heads
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setProducts([...products, res.data]);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Just what I'm checking for on laravel so far:

```
return response()->json($request->hasFile('file'), 200);
```

Which returns false for some reason.

Sorry I'm pretty new to react-native.

Comment: Did you try with postman?

Comment: and try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521679/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-with-expo

Comment: omg.. the reason it wasn't working was because I was using the network inspector in react-native-debugger!

Answer (score 0):

All the code is good here, to solve this problem, don't use the network inspector tool in react-native-debugger while uploading images. It doesn't register files for some reason. Happy Coding!