# How Do I Convert Image URI into Byte Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm uploading image using `expo-image-picker`. but the issue is I want to send the image to the server through WebAPI in the form of Byte. So how can I convert the image URI into Byte? if anyone have experience on it so kindly share.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.getPermissionAsync();
    }
    getPermissionAsync = async () => {
        if (Constants.platform.ios) {
            const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
            }
        }
    };
    _pickImage = async () => {
        try {
            let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                allowsEditing: true,
                aspect: [4, 3],
            });
            console.log(result);

            if (!result.cancelled) {
                this.setState({ image: result.uri });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Card>
                    <CardItem>
                        <Body>
                            <Button block primary onPress={() => this._pickImage()}>
                                <Text>Add Activity</Text>
                            </Button>
                            {this.state.image && <Image source={{ uri: this.state.image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} /> }
                        </Body>
                    </CardItem>
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@zain143/imagepicker-from-camera-roll-(permissions))

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273250/7427111 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

_pickImage = async () => {
  try {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      base64: true,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      let imageByte = new Buffer(result.base64, "base64");

      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
  }
};
```

NOTE: You will need [buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) package.

Comment: No it returns me unwanted result.